# Why does indent disappear in lists?

Tags: lists, indentation, paragraphs

Consider this small document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
\item%
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This has two paragraphs outside a list environment, and two paragraphs inside a list environment. I've noticed in this situation that paragraphs outside lists have their first line indented, whereas paragraphs inside lists do not have any indent:

[image: Compiled document with markings]

Why does this occur? Can I restore the indentation inside a list?

**EDIT:** I notice that in lists, by default paragraphs are separated by blank lines. Preferably a solution should also get rid of that. (For context, I'm writing up a solution to an assignment, and nearly every paragraph is inside an `enumerate` or similar.)

Comment: "why" questions are hard to answer, the list paragraph shape is settable as are the outer paragraphs the standard latex classes chose choose that layout as presumably the original author preferred  it that way. you can set \listparindent` and other list parameters to achieve other shapes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\item` properties  can be formatted with `enumitem`. Then you can use `listparindent` for `enumerate` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{parsep=0pt}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\blindtext

    \begin{enumerate}[listparindent=1.5em]

        \item
        \blindtext

        \blindtext

    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Thanks to @David, you can also set `\parsep` to `0` if you want to get rid of that space.

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, this doesn't entirely answer my question: I also asked _why_ this behaviour happens. I also notice that this method still preserves that extra horizontal space between paragraphs in the list; do you have any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: @bradrn AFAIK `enumerate` is kind of old and `enumitem` gives you more advantage and options comparing to  list environments such as `itemize` and `enumerate`. However my understanding is `enumerate` eliminates the paragraph indentation by default. Regarding that horizontal space, I'll have a look.

Comment: @bradrn You can always use something like this `\vspace{-0.1cm}` after the paragraph. But it's not the best solution of course.

Comment: @bradrn the paragraph space is `\parsep` (or `parsep` in the enumitem interface) so you can set that to 0pt

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah In my 'real' code, I'm already using `enumitem`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! I'll try that out when I can get a chance to work on my assignment again - I'm fairly busy right now...

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behaviour is that inside `enumerate` the length `\parindent` is set to zero.  So you can not use a simple `\indent` as usual in normal text to get the space of `\parindent` set.

You can simulate the ususal behaviour in normal text with the following code (See `<=====` for important code):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem} % <===============================================
\newlength{\enumerateparindent} % <=====================================

\begin{document}

\setlength{\enumerateparindent}{\parindent} % <=========================
\blindtext

\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\parindent}{\enumerateparindent} % <=========================
%\show\parindent 
%\value{\parindent}
\item%
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{enumerate}

Version 2:
\begin{enumerate}[listparindent=\enumerateparindent] % <================
\item%
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

and the wished result:

[image]

Please see that `\setlength{\parindent}{\enumerateparindent}` does only work in that `enumerate` list you placed the command inside ...

If you are already using package `enumitem` -- as mentioned in an comment -- you can use it to use the same indent defined in `\parindent` with version 2 in my mwe.

The you get the resulting version 2:

[image]